# How to Get Category name along with product_id in Solr response

Tags: php, magento, solr

I've got this problem that I can't solve. Partly because I can't explain it with the right terms. I'm new to this so sorry for this clumsy question.

Below you can see an overview of my goal.

I'm working with Magento CE 1.7.0.2 & Solr 4.6.0.

I'm searching for products its working fine,But plan is if i search with any of one category name that should return all the product from that category.

Foe Example, I have the categories like this

```
Mens
  - Shirts
    -- Casual Shirts
    -- Formal Shirts
  - T-Shirts
  ......
  ......
  ......
  ......
  ......
```

Now i'm trying to search with a word **Formal Shirts** it is showing " No Products found "

I can understand why its showing like that but my goal it should return **Formal Shirts** category products.

How can i do this one ?

Any Ideas ?

Comment: It is unclear. Can u explain it clearly?

Comment: first of all, stored the category id associated with products in a multivalued field... for e.g. if you have a product `xyz` which has id 1 and its associated with category_id 1(Men), 2 (shirts), 3(Casual shirts), 4(Formal Shirts), then index this id's in a multivalued field say `category_id` and value as array containing 1,2,3,4. And then pass category_id to solr to search a product under that category

Comment: @KarthikSurianarayanan when i search with category name that search result should be all products of that category also.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the category ID you can load the controller and get the name:

```
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load('RESPONSE CAT ID');
echo $category->getName();
```

HTH

Comment: In magento means like this but i want this in solr